# Can I consider both noon and evening meals as dinner?

Tags: comparisons

Can I consider both noon and evening meals as dinner?

So, I have been thinking about the conflicts among the meanings of Lunch, Dinner and Supper. I have found many satisfying answers. But the thing is, I am from a South-Asian nation where people have meals 3 times a day. While we have light food for morning meals, we have heavy food both at noon or in the afternoon and in the evening or at the night(Normally 9:00 pm - 12:30 am). We do have light meal in the evening but we don't consider it as a proper meal. In that case, can I consider them both as dinners? Sorry, my English skill is very poor.... .

Comment: Personally, I would say "dinner" for the largest meal.  Some may have dinner in the middle of the day and supper in the evening.  Others may have lunch in the middle of the day and dinner in the evening.  Incredibly to me, those who do not have to get up the next day to go to work, may have lunch, then supper, and then dinner only at midnight...  I believe that light "supper" may be called instead "tea" in England.